# Some of Apache's VirtualHosts (the ones with .com domains) stopped responding, but not the others

Tags: apache-http-server, raspberry-pi, nextcloud

I have a Raspberry Pi 4 serving 5 different sites. 4 of them are just static, minimal home project sites, and one of them is a snap Nextcloud instance which runs through a reverse proxy. I have every virtualhost with ssl configured through certbot and everything was running OK until today when Nextcloud stopped responding.

After checking all the other domains, I've seen that (coincidentally?) the .com domains do not respond, while the others do.

`/var/log/apache2/error.log` looks like this:

```
[Wed Oct 14 19:06:13.012069 2020] [mpm_event:error] [pid 2059:tid 281473471475728] AH03490: scoreboard is full, not at MaxRequestWorkers.Increase ServerLimit.
[Wed Oct 14 19:06:14.013288 2020] [mpm_event:error] [pid 2059:tid 281473471475728] AH03490: scoreboard is full, not at MaxRequestWorkers.Increase ServerLimit.
[Wed Oct 14 19:06:15.014486 2020] [mpm_event:error] [pid 2059:tid 281473471475728] AH03490: scoreboard is full, not at MaxRequestWorkers.Increase ServerLimit.
[Wed Oct 14 19:06:16.015707 2020] [mpm_event:error] [pid 2059:tid 281473471475728] AH03490: scoreboard is full, not at MaxRequestWorkers.Increase ServerLimit.
[Wed Oct 14 19:06:17.016931 2020] [mpm_event:error] [pid 2059:tid 281473471475728] AH03490: scoreboard is full, not at MaxRequestWorkers.Increase ServerLimit.
[Wed Oct 14 19:06:18.018247 2020] [mpm_event:error] [pid 2059:tid 281473471475728] AH03490: scoreboard is full, not at MaxRequestWorkers.Increase ServerLimit.
[Wed Oct 14 19:06:19.019550 2020] [mpm_event:error] [pid 2059:tid 281473471475728] AH03490: scoreboard is full, not at MaxRequestWorkers.Increase ServerLimit.
[Wed Oct 14 19:18:31.037054 2020] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 2059:tid 281473471475728] AH00493: SIGUSR1 received.  Doing graceful restart
[Wed Oct 14 19:18:31.065424 2020] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 2059:tid 281473471475728] AH00489: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.1.1f configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Oct 14 19:18:31.065478 2020] [core:notice] [pid 2059:tid 281473471475728] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

`sudo apachectl configtest` shows an OK syntax and `sudo systemctl status apache2.service -l --no-pager` shows:

```
● apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2020-10-14 17:53:55 UTC; 1h 49min ago
       Docs: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/
    Process: 1825 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 307170 ExecReload=/usr/sbin/apachectl graceful (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 2059 (apache2)
      Tasks: 163 (limit: 9258)
     CGroup: /system.slice/apache2.service
             ├─  2059 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
             ├─307174 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
             ├─307175 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
             ├─307230 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
             ├─307258 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
             ├─307287 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
             └─307315 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start

Oct 14 18:56:38 raspberrypi4 systemd[1]: Reloading The Apache HTTP Server.
Oct 14 18:56:38 raspberrypi4 systemd[1]: Reloaded The Apache HTTP Server.
Oct 14 19:00:23 raspberrypi4 systemd[1]: Reloading The Apache HTTP Server.
Oct 14 19:00:23 raspberrypi4 systemd[1]: Reloaded The Apache HTTP Server.
Oct 14 19:05:02 raspberrypi4 systemd[1]: Reloading The Apache HTTP Server.
Oct 14 19:05:02 raspberrypi4 systemd[1]: Reloaded The Apache HTTP Server.
Oct 14 19:05:18 raspberrypi4 systemd[1]: Reloading The Apache HTTP Server.
Oct 14 19:05:18 raspberrypi4 systemd[1]: Reloaded The Apache HTTP Server.
Oct 14 19:18:30 raspberrypi4 systemd[1]: Reloading The Apache HTTP Server.
Oct 14 19:18:31 raspberrypi4 systemd[1]: Reloaded The Apache HTTP Server.
```

I have very little experience with Apache, and after some touching `/etc/apache2/mods-available/mpm_prefork.conf` to add the ServerLimit directive (it was not there) with different values I have not found a solution, so I deleted ServerLimit again. Any recommendations? That file looks like:

```
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
        StartServers              5
        MinSpareServers           5
        MaxSpareServers          10
        MaxRequestWorkers         150
        MaxConnectionsPerChild   0
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Have you increased *MaxRequestWorkers* per the error log?

Comment: Why exactly is MaxConnectionsPerChild set to 0?

Comment: @Ramhound I tried 250 and saw no difference, same errors. 0 is the default value for MaxConnectionsPerChild, I did not touch it.

Comment: Have you tried rebooting the entire system.  The logs indicate the service restarted several times within a few seconds (twice within 5 seconds).

Comment: Yes, I rebooted several times.